# Adding NuGet packages from nuget.org in a custom VS item template

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, envdte, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to add NuGet packages automatically when adding a custom item template in Visual Studio. The packages need to be referenced from nuget.org, deploying them locally in the ItemTemplate-Zipfiles is unfortunately no option.

What I have tried so far:

1.) Altering the `packages.config` programatically. As this requires the project to be reloaded and manual intervention to install the added packages, this is not really feasible

2.) Using `NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop` in the template wizard as well as adding it to the vstemplate file requires the NuGet packages to be stored locally. Since I need to them to be installed from nuget.org, this is no option either.

3.) Using the NuGet-API doesn't seem to work either, since it does not take the "project" parameter passed to it from `envdte` or `vslangproj`.

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved it with this code:

```cs
List<string> packagesToInstall = new List<string>();
packagesToInstall.Add("SomeNuGetPackageIdentifier");
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
IVsPackageInstaller2 installer = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller2>();

//Loop through the list of Strings and install the Packages.
foreach (string package in packagesToInstall)
{
    try
    {
        installer.InstallLatestPackage(null, vsProj.Project, package, false, false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        continue;
    }
}
```